# Reading a file, who's lines change type

Tags: c#, class, data-structures, interface

This should be simple but the brain isn't quite caffeine'd up yet this morning.

I have an invoice file (actually dataset, but, whatever).  I'm reading it line by line, top down.  If the line has an O in the type column, it's the start of a new order, and contains order info, and section heading details.  When it contains an S, it has the same heading details for a sub section.  The other lines are the details for their respective sections with item number and quantities (Related to headings in O/S lines).

example

```
O  o123  typea typeb typec
   1234    3     2     6
   2345    1     0     2
S        typed typee typef
   1634    3     2     6
   2645    1     0     2
O  o123  typea typeb typec
   1234    3     2     6
   2345    1     0     2
S        typed typee typef
   1634    3     2     6
   2645    1     0     2
S        typed typee typef
   1634    3     2     6
   2645    1     0     2
```

I am not struggling with changing type, and handling the state machine aspects of reading the file.  What I'm struggling with is the object model.

I initially read the row into a generic line class, then need to convert it to it's proper type...  but what's the proper way to lay out these classes?  How should my interfaces look so I can write this cleanly.  Should there be an abstract class?

If it makes a difference, I'm coding in c# (framework 3.5).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some flavor of the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.

This is usually implemented by having a number of classes deriving from a common base or implementing a common interface -- this depends on the relations between the classes. Let's go with the second option and assume `ICommon`. Then, you populate a map of "distinctive values" to instances of `Action<ICommon>`.

In your example, we might have:

```
var map = Dictionary<string, Action<ICommon>()
{
    { "O", () => new Order() },
    { "S", () => new Subsection() },
};
```

Then, you create the factory method that takes whatever your input is, finds the appropriate action from the map, creates the object and returns it to the caller:

```
public static ICommon CreateCommon(FileLine line)
{
     // assume map is visible
     var producer = map[line.Type];
     return producer();
}
```

That's all there is to it. Usually all of this is packaged into a static class, and depending on the particulars of your case the map may be populated with hardcoded data, or automatically by some algorithm (think `static` constructor of the class that packages these) or even programmatically by your code before using the factory method.